# Using Nightwatch - is it possible to past test variables to beforeEach?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a beforeEach function that creates a booking so that my test can approve it. It works fine but I want to have a test for each different kind of booking, let's say for example a booking from US and AU.

This is what my code looks like right now (simplified example)

```
module.exports = {
  beforeEach: async function (browser, done) {
    const bookingId = await createBooking('US') //assume this exists and creates the booking based on passed in country
    browser.globals.currentBookingId = bookingId
    done()
  },
  'User can approve a US booking': function (browser) {
    const bookingId = browser.globals.currentBookingId

    const bookingPage = browser.page['bookings']()

    bookingPage.navigate(bookingId)

    //approve booking

    browser.end()
  }
}
```

The question, is if I want to add another test, **User can approve an AU booking**, is there any way to reuse the beforeEach code with different input variables?

Also, is there any way to return the bookingId from the beforeEach? I'm not sure if setting it in globals is the best way.

Originally I wasn't using beforeEach, I was just putting the createBooking steps in the test itself but it's asynchronous and it seems like the test functions aren't allowed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've thought about a possible solution. I could just set up all the bookings at the start in a before function ie

```
module.exports = {
  before: async function (browser, done) {
    const countries = ["US", "AU"]

    for (let country of countries){
      browser.globals.bookingIds[country] = await createBooking(country)
    }

    done()
  },
  'User can approve a US booking': function (browser) {
    const bookingId = browser.globals.bookingIds.US

    const bookingPage = browser.page['bookings']()

    bookingPage.navigate(bookingId)

    //approve booking

    browser.end()
  },
   'User can approve a AU booking': function (browser) {
    const bookingId = browser.globals.bookingIds.AU

    const bookingPage = browser.page['bookings']()

    bookingPage.navigate(bookingId)

    //approve booking

    browser.end()
  }
}
```